# How to connect to database using orm third party (REALM)?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, orm

I was trying to implement sqlite db using Realm Orm. Now i want to change the sqlite db to mysql db and do the transactions via php. Can I use the realm orm to do the stuff ?

Comment: In order to answer it would help a lot if you could be much more specific. First, Realm is not an Orm on top of sqlite. It is a database on it's own with an object oriented API. It does not run on top of mysql either. It only runs on mobile devices and not servers (unless you include Mac as a server).
I assume you are developing an Android app? I don't think that's possible with php at all.

Comment: thank you FYI . I learned something new. Yeah i am developing android app and trying to change the sqlite db to server db.